# ActionScript 3 sort an array with numbers and letters not working as expected

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm trying to sort the users cards in a card game, for example all user's aces to stand close to each other.
I'm using this:

p1cards is an array with elements like "c8", "d9", "h1", letters stand from card symbol (Club, Diamond, Hearts) and number is the card value (1 is Ace, 2 is 2, and so on)

```
p1cards.sort(sortOrder);

    function sortOrder(a,b)
    {
        var aN = parseInt(a.substr(1));
        var bN = parseInt(b.substr(1));

        if (aN > bN)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that sorted card like the 8d, 8c are switching places to 8c, 8d, kind of randomly, when I draw a new card.

Any help will be apreciated.

See in picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ticj.jpg

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define in your sort what to do when the values are the same, so depending what item gets slotted in as `a` and which is `b` (which you have no control over) will determine the order.  Tell your sort function what to do when the items are the same:

```
function sortOrder(a,b)
{
    var aN = parseInt(a.substr(1));
    var bN = parseInt(b.substr(1));

    if(aN == bN){
         //they are the same, so add a secondary sort based off suit
         var aS = a.substr(0,1); //grab the first character which is the suit
         var bS = b.substr(0,1);

         if(aS > bS) return 1;
         if(bS > aS) return -1;
         return 0;
    }

    if (aN > bN)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have the same behaviour.

Comment: That made it, thank you very much! Have a great day.

Comment: I think this is what @null is saying to do too (didn't read his question until just now), give them an upvote when you have the rep for it.

Comment: Yes, but you did the "extra mile" and solved it faster. I will upvote when I'll have the rep.

Comment: plus 1 for example code (boy that rule that comments cannot start with "+1" is quite silly)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an undefined behaviour that you are not happy with, simply define the behaviour that you like.

In your case, if both numbers are the same, evaluate the card symbol additionally.
this makes the order of two cards unambigiously clear and the sort operation (for these two cards) idempotent.